# Installation problems with ASP MVC Release Candidate 1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation

I've tried installing RC1 must have been 5 times already and always run into the same issue around the "Configuring Templates' step.  I've tried everything I can think of but now I have neither RC1 or Beta.  Has anyone run into this error?  Any suggestions for what I can do?

Screenshot of my problem [here](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/4jr9YoJPo3x_vv66Ipd5Cg) (not sure why I can't place it as an image.

(Cross-posted to the ASP.NET forum [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1378638.aspx) but I don't really expect much of useful response there.)

**Edit:** Here is everything I can think of that I have installed that might possibly be affecting this:  Coderush, Refactor Pro!, Source Outliner, TestDriven.Net, MbUnit (installs some templates), Some DevExpress plug-ins (GhostDoc, CR_Classcleaner), F#, Spec #

I have also installed (and uninstalled) ASP.NET MVC Beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, it was either F# or Spec# that was giving me problems since I don't really use either much I uninstalled both and RC1 went fine.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that removing Spec# solved the install problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just happen to run across this... do you have Clone Detective for VS installed?  Seems as though some people had trouble installing the MVC Beta with it installed.

http://www.codeplex.com/CloneDetectiveVS/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=11549

Comment: No I don't and MVC Beta installed (and uninstalled) with no problems

Comment: This solved my problem :) All good after uninstalling CloneDetective.

Answer (score 1):

After the obvious step of removing any older installations of MVC, I've heard the templates can have issues with Visual Studio add-ons. Try removing any add-ons to VS you might have running, then run the installer.

Comment: What, really?  That is a major hindrance, I've got Coderush, Refactor Pro, F#, Spec #, Source Outliner, and a couple  Developer Express plugins.  This is a pretty massive fail, now I have to weight playing with ASP MVC versus this huge bother.

Comment: Yea, I don't use any add-ons... so not stating from personal experience. Just from what I read. I doubt its ALL add-ons... more likely only certain add-ons (but which, who knows. ;D )

Answer (score 0):

You don't state explicitly, did you install any other previous versions (such as beta or preview)?  You will need to uninstall Beta or Preview x before installing the RC.

Comment: I did have Beta previously and I uninstalled it first (It wouldn't even let me install while Beta was on there) I have double and triple checked this.